# Rewrite a complex link .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My old website have product link like this

```
domain-name/index.php/product-category/detail/603/product-name.html
```

my new Wordpress website have product link like this

```
domain-name/product-category/product-name
```

i config in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product-category/detail/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-]*).html /product-category/$2 [QSA,L]
```

in permalink i config:

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

The new site works very correctly, but the old link is not working. Old link always redirect to error 404 absolute, i want to keep old link on google auto redirect to new link. Does anyone have a solution for this please, thank u very much.

Comment: What is "google auto redirect"?

Comment: it mean when click on an old link on google search result, it'll redirect to new link on my website :) sorry for my bad english :')

Comment: OK, so you refer to your own redirection rules. Those have nothing to do with google. You need to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your rule modified to actually match the requested URL you show:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/product-category/detail/\d+/([\w-]+)\.html /product-category/$2 [QSA,END]
```

But more likely you want the more flexible variant:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/([\w-]+)/detail/\d+/([\w-]+)\.html /$1/$2 [QSA,END]
```

You should prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you have no access to that you can use a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but that comes with some disadvantages.

I could imagine that it also makes sense to send an external redirection to clients still requesting those old URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/([\w-]+)/detail/\d+/([\w-]+)\.html /$1/$2 [QSA,R=301,END]
```

For that it might make sense to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once you checked that everything works as expected. That prevents annoying caching issues...

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been resolved :)